# Regular expression issue in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to extract the below pattern from a string using Ruby and I don't seem to be getting too far on Ruby...

Here is the regex I am using `\/p\/[\w-\/]*[\d+]`

And here is the type of string I am trying to extract.

```
/p/hyphenated-words/more-hyphenated-words/102049294
```

So in short the string always starts with /p/ will end with multiple digits and contain one or more sub directories with possible hyphens.

My regex works on some online expression testers but not in Ruby.

Comment: You should check out http://rubular.com where you can test your Ruby regex live in the browser. I use it all the time.

Comment: Hi Johannes, I have been using Rubular.  It's pretty handy - it wasn't working earlier.  I also use [link](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) if I think something not working as it should be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to @Mark Byers answer :

```
 /p/[\w-/]*[\d+]
```

The [\d+] part of your regex is irrelevant. The reason is that it is preceded by a greedy quantifier which quantifies a class which in turn contains `\w`. `\w` translates into `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` which will "eat" any digts that come after it.

Finally instead of [\d+] simply use \d (if you must).

Answer (score 5):

The hyphen inside a character class means a character range. Escape it to make it a literal hyphen. That is, change this `[\w-\/]` to `[\w\-\/]`.

Also change `[\d+]` to `\d+` without the square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose forward slashes in ruby.
So your regex should look something like `\/\p\/\` this would exactly match `/p/` 
Above posts would help you with the remaining parts

Comment: You only need to do that if you're using `/` as your regex delimiter. My preference would be to do `%r{/p/}` rather than `/\/p\//`.